# Telegram bot sheduled notifications

Tags: python, notifications, telegram-bot

I need to send notifications through the Telegram bot for 5 days every day from the time the user started using the bot for the first time. Is it possible to record the time when the chat id was created and do personalized notifications to each user?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [Telegram's Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat) exposes that info.

But, you can record the first occurrence of a new chat ID yourself to achieve this.

Depending on your stack, use case, and environment, you could either use a full-blown database, a SQLite DB (amounts to a single file), a simple key-value store or even just a text file to do this.